# Make class as Parcelable

Tags: java, android, kotlin, parcelable, parcel

I am currently trying to make one of my classes implement `Parcelable` but I can't do it properly. This is the class.

```
    class T(val eyes:Int,val img:ImageButton){
         var image = img
         var value = eyes
         var isPressed = false
    }
```

Android Studio suggests that my constructor should look similar to this when implementing `Parcelable`, but I don't know how to use a parcel to initialize my `ImageButton`.

```
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readInt(),
            //parcel.
            ) {
         value = parcel.readInt()
         isPressed = parcel.readByte() != 0.toByte()
    }
```

Tried to use a parcel. any and cast it to an `ImageButton` without success, any suggestions on how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't make an ImageButton (or any other View) part of a Parcelable. It has references to Context, resources, other Views, etc. Also, you can only make properties part of your Parcelable if they are collections, primitives, or other Parcelables.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to make a class like this, you can create it in this way

   ```
   class T(var eyes: Int, var img: ImageButton, var isPressed: Boolean = false)
   ```
2. ImageButton class doesn't implement the `Parcelable` interface, in this case, you cannot pass it into Parcel. It's not a good approach to put Views into Parcel, you can save their state into primitives or classes which implements `Parcelable` and restore it after that. For example, if you want to pass a text from `EditText` to another activity, you can put this text into Parcel as `String`, and restore it in the next `Activity`.

Comment: With that information I made some changes to the design to avoid passing the image to this class and thereafter made the class implement the Parcelable interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kotlin always use data class for model. and use `@Parcelize` annotation so you don't need to write extra boilerplate code. But in your case you can't `Parcelize` `ImageButton` it's not a class that implements `Parcelable` interface

In case you are searching about a normal way to implement, Just use like that:

```
@Parcelize
data class UserInformationData(
    var userId :  String? = null,
    var firstName :  String? = null,
    var lastName  :  String? = null,
    var email :  String? = null,
    var gender :  String? = null,
    var dateOfBirth :  String? = null,
    var phoneNumber :  String? = null
):Parcelable
```